# G-equivariance at the Lie algebra level

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry, equivariant-maps, moment-map

Let $\vec{x}, \vec{p} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be coordinates on 6D phase space.
Consider the lift of the standard action of SO(3):
$$\psi_O(\vec{x}, \vec{p}) = (O\cdot\vec{x}, O\cdot\vec{p})
$$

This action is hamiltonian with comoment map L given by the angular momentum:
$$L(\xi) = \vec{L}\cdot\vec{\xi}
$$
where o(3) has been identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$ with Lie bracket given by the cross product.

This is a Lie Algebra homomorphism from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $C^\infty(M)$

$$\{L(\xi), L(\eta)\} = L ([\xi, \eta])
$$

The existence of the comoment map implies the existence of the moment map and hence SO(3) equivariance of $L$.

$$L\circ \psi = \text{Ad}^* \circ L
$$

And so in this context I can see
$$\text{LA homomorphism} \quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad \text{equivariance}
$$

---

Now, I am working through *Variations on a theme by Kepler*, Guillemin and Sternberg.

They give another comoment map:
$$F(\xi) = \vec{F}\cdot\vec{\xi}$$
where $\vec{F} = \vec{p} \times \vec{L}$ is the Lenz vector.

One can check the map $F$ is SO(3)-equivariant by showing the adjoint map of SO(3) on o(3) is the standard action of SO(3) on o(3) identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$.
The result then follows from the fact SO(3) preserves the cross product.

The authors give as a consequence of this:
"This map ($F$) is SO(3) equivariant, which implies, at the Lie algebra level, that:"
$$\{L(\xi), F(\eta)\} = F([\xi, \eta])
$$
Although this appears natural I am not sure how I can prove this.

I can see the difference with the previous section is that this time the map $F$ is equivariant w.r.t. the action generated by $L$ (and not by F itself), the standard action of SO(3) given at the beginning:
$$F \circ \psi^L = (\text{Ad}_L)^* \circ F
$$
It appears the result of the first section is a special case where the map generates the action under which it is equivariant.

Any tips on proving $\{L(\xi), F(\eta)\} = F([\xi, \eta])$ as a consequence of SO(3) equivariance of the map $F$ would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\xi\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$, let $\hat{\xi}$ denote the vector field on $T^*\mathbb{R}^3$ generated by $\xi$, i.e.
$$
\hat{\xi}(x,p) := \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg\vert_{t=0}(\exp(t\xi)x, \exp(t\xi)p) = (\xi x, \xi p).
$$
The essential idea is that $L(\xi)$ is the Hamiltonian corresponding to Hamiltonian vector field $\hat{\xi}$, meaning that (with Guillemin and Sternberg's conventions}
$$
\hat{\xi} = -\{L(\xi), \cdot\}
$$
(note that the right hand side is a mapping from $C^\infty(T^*\mathbb{R}^3)$ to itself that satisfies the Leibniz property, and hence is a vector field on $T^*\mathbb{R}^3$, so this makes sense). Given this, the result you are trying to prove can be reformulated as
$$
\hat\xi(F(\eta)) = -F([\xi,\eta]) = F(-\operatorname{ad}_\xi\eta) = (-\operatorname{ad}_\xi^*F)\eta
$$
i.e.
$$
\hat{\xi}F = -\operatorname{ad}_\xi^*F.
$$
This is simply the infinitesimal version of the equivariance property
$$
F\circ \psi_O = \operatorname{Ad}_{O^{-1}}^*F
$$
(just take $O = \exp(t\xi)$, and differentiate with respect to $t$ at $t=0$).
So if you accept the latter, the former follows immediately.

Comment: Brilliant ! This is all very clear thank you.
I am only confused by the last line, it differs by a minus sign to what I'd expect (I would have $O$ instead of $O^{-1}$ on the right, this is the definition I read in daSilva's notes on symplectic geometry, is this another case of convention ?).  
I would have $\hat{\xi}F = \dfrac{d}{dt}\exp(t\xi)\Big\rvert_{t=0}f =\dfrac{d}{dt}f\circ\exp(-t\xi)\Big\rvert_{t=0} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\Big\rvert_{t=0}(F\circ\psi_{O^{-1}})$  
while $-\text{ad}^*_{\xi}F = \dfrac{d}{dt}\Big\rvert_{t=0}(\text{Ad}^*_{O^{-1}}F)$

Comment: My definition of $\hat{\xi}f$ would be $\frac{d}{dt}\big\vert_{t=0}f\circ \exp(t\xi)$. Also my definition of $\operatorname{Ad}^*_{O^{-1}}F$ is $F\circ \operatorname{Ad}_{O^{-1}}$; some authors use the notation  $\operatorname{Ad}^*_OF$ instead. The inverse is needed to ensure the coadjoint action is a *left* action, i.e. $\operatorname{Ad}^*_{O_1^{-1}}\operatorname{Ad}^*_{O_2^{-1}} = \operatorname{Ad}^*_{(O_1O_2)^{-1}}$.

Comment: Oh, I was careless with the first part, and it seems the author did in fact use $\text{Ad}^*_O$ to denote your $\text{Ad}^*_{O^{-1}}$. Thanks very much for your help, it's all very clear now

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. I always find it difficult to remember Guillemin and Sternberg's conventions, since they're very inconsistent with them. In their book "Geometric Asymptotics", for example, there are places where they use two different conventions *on the same page* - it's annoying. It's worth keeping this in mind when reading their books/papers.